# What is the best way of logic separation using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and it's really cool, but sometimes I get stacked with some architectural problems.
Let me explain with an example.

Assume we have an app that allowes user to create a bill.
Every bill has some lines within itself. Each line represents some kind of good or service and has such properties as
title, quantity, cost and sum. So in JSON it could be representated like this:

```
"goods": [
    {
        "title": "Apple",
        "quantity": 3,
        "cost": 5.00,
        "sum": 15.00 // 5.00 × 3
    },
    {...}
]
```

A bill also has its total amount, which is usually a sum of all item sums. So if we have 3 apples that cost $15.00 and 5 bananas that cost $10.00, than we have our bill's total amount of $25.00.

The question is about what is the better way to calculate amounts in every scope.
One approach is to have only one scope (for bill) with some defined methods to calculate sum in every step. For example (pseudocode):

```
$scope.getTotalInItem = function(item) {
    return item.quantity * item.cost
}

$scope.getTotal = function() {
    amount = 0
    for item in $scope.items
    amount += $scope.getTotalInItem(item)
        return amount
}
```

I don't like this approach because it mixes all the logic in one place. But allows to simply fetch data from server and use it without preparations.

Another approach is to create a class for each calculation level. Something like this:

```
function Good(title, quantity, cost){
    this.total = function(){
        return this.quantity * this.cost
    }
}

function Bill(goods){
    this.goods = goods
    this.total = function(){
        amount = 0
        for good in this.goods
            amount += good.total()
        return amount
    }
}
```

I'd prefer this approach as it has logic level separation. But I don't know how to better use it with Angular. This approach doesn't allow me to simply fetch the JSON from server and change it.

Here is the demo of these two approaches: http://plnkr.co/edit/7t56sIUY83Rnowe8Zb3z?p=preview

I think I shall prepare my model after every data fetch and before every data push. So I need some helper functions such as toJSON() and fromJSON().
What is the best practice of doing such things with Angular?

Comment: as soon as see `in every scope` use a service to share data and /or methods. Inject that service where needed

Comment: @charlietfl So should I better create a service where to place a constructor for items (goods in my example) and then iterate over an initial array to create instances of Good class for each object in that array?

Comment: is very hard to say since not known here how often you use what. If you create a demo in plunker would help.

Comment: I will make a demo today and then let you know about that.

Comment: Here is the plunker demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/7t56sIUY83Rnowe8Zb3z?p=preview

Comment: see if this helps  http://plnkr.co/edit/68BMEmKYiLN2Vqu8ruWI?p=preview

Comment: IMHO this logic should be either in a controller or in a separate service. The service I added for ServerData is a mock of real data coming from server.

Comment: no reason can't have methods and data requests in same service

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you have to account for is the dirty checking. Recently I coded an invoice and I found something nasty. I had table with products and I used `value="{{ IVACalc().toFixed(2) }}"` The problem with this is that every time the user modifies an input, anywhere in the page (assuming that you have only a main controller), you're going to perform this calculation again.

When you press a key, there's 2 events: onkeydown and onkeyup. 2 calculations per key, you need to handle it. In this scenario it's a good decision to create a specific controller for the lines of the invoice and use a service to share data.

This is own I code my angularjs projects.

I create an init.js file where I declare my app, dependencies, services and some helpers. I wrap external plugins (example:toastr) in a service, some programmers might create a directive.

```
    var ViewModule = angular.module('ViewModule',[]);

    ViewModule.factory('ViewService', function($rootScope){
      var sharedService = {};
      sharedService.message = '';


      sharedService.init = function(message){
        switch (message){
          case 'productPickView':
            $rootScope.$broadcast('productPickInit');
          break;
          case 'loginView':
            $rootScope.$broadcast('loginViewInit');
          break;
          default :
        }
      };

   //using toastr 
   var NotificationCenterModule = angular.module('NotificationCenterModule', []);
   NotificationCenterModule.factory('NotificationCenter', function($rootScope){
   var sharedService = {};
   ...

   var app = angular.module('TouchApp',['ViewModule',
                                     'ConfirmationModule',
                                     'ui.bootstrap',
                                     'ngGrid',
                                     'appConfig',
```

For the controllers is

```
app.controller("productPickCtrl", function($scope, $http, ViewService, 
ConfirmationService, appConfig, NotificationCenter){
```

I want my code to be easily readable, that's how I base my coding style. It's easier for your teammates to understand and makes your life a lot easier. Don't forget to use javadoc or similar.

Comment: So should I better create a service where to place a constructor for items (goods in my example) and then iterate over an initial array to create instances of Good class for each object in that array?

Comment: Look a this example: http://pastebin.com/TRPs23kx I'm assuming that you want to share data between the bill Controller and bill's lines controller. You can make a copy or pass by reference.

Comment: Yes, I understand about shared services. The question was where it is the best way to place calculation logic — into general controller or create a separate controller for each line in a bill.

Comment: Yes, a separated controller but for the lines, not a controller per line. If you perform lots of calculations, you're going to have performance issues. In my case I used 1 controllers and discovered this but there's no performance penalty so far. Since you want to separate and organize your application login, separating is a good decision.

Comment: So my calculations for line and for total bill should be the methods of the same object?

Comment: Yes, if don't have performance issues it's ok. My invoice controller can handle around 500 lines without lag, on a modest computer. Creating 2 objects allows to separate the code and solve any performance issue, if they exist.